# display currency picker in without using xml file in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, currency

Basically this code :

```
<?php if($this->getCurrencyCount()>1): ?>
<div class="block block-currency">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Select Your Currency') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <select name="currency" title="<?php echo $this->__('Select Your Currency') ?>" onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
        <?php foreach ($this->getCurrencies() as $_code => $_name): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $this->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code) ?>"<?php if($_code==$this->getCurrentCurrencyCode()): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                <?php echo $_name ?> - <?php echo $_code ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

AND

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="header">
            <block type="directory/currency" name="custom_currency_selector" template="currency/currency.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

code help to display the currecny switcher in the header of magento page. But I want to use only currecny.phtml code directly into header without using any xml file so what should I have to write in place of : `$this->`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Got it.

```
<?php echo  $this->getLayout()->createBlock('directory/currency')->setTemplate('directory/currency.phtml')->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: You can mark your own answer as accepted if you would like, or wait and someone may be able to help you further.